# wget There is a way to avoid creating the index.html file?

Tags: shell, wget

This command creates an index.html file with the list of files inside. Only sometimes it overwrites the original file with the file list.

```
 wget --mirror --convert-links --page-requisites --no-parent --reject "*.gz" -P /home/admin/${lid} http://${zona}/farmacie/${lid}/
```

So I find that in the browser appears the Parent Directory instead of the original index.html. How can I do this?

Thanks